# How to find the prefix of a word for nlp

Tags: python, nlp

I want to find the prefix of a word for nlp purposes(interested in morphological negation).

For example, I want to know "unable" is negative, but "university" does not have any sort of negation. I have been using the startswith python function so far, but obviously there can be some issues.

Does anyone have any experience with finding prefixes of words? I feel like there should be some library or api, but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: see [stemmer](https://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html) and [lemmatizer](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/wordnet.html)

Comment: I don't think those work...I've tried lemmatizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of a full morphological analyser, you can work around this with exception lists and longest matching.

For example: you assume *un-* expresses negation. First, find longer prefixes (such as *uni-*), and match for that first, before looking at *un-*. There will be a handful of exceptions, such as *uninteresting*, which you can check for separately. This will be a fairly smallish list. Then, once all the *uni-* words have been dealt with, anything starting with *un-* is a candidate, though there will also be exceptions, such as *under*.

A slightly better solution is possible if you have a basic word list: cut of *un-* from the beginning of the string, and check whether the remainder is in your word list. *University* will become *iversity*, which is not in your list, and thus it's not the *un-* prefix. However, *uninteresting* will become *interesting*, which is, so here you have found a valid prefix. All you need for this is a list of non-negated words. You can of course also use this for other prefixes, such as the [alpha privative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_privative), as in *atypical* the remainder *typical* will be in your list.

If you don't have such a list, simply split your text into tokens, sort and unique them, and then scan down the line of words beginning with your candidate prefixes. It's a bit tedious, but the numbers of relevant words are not that big. It's what we all did in NLP 30 years ago... :)